# Exchange 2013 EWS API create calendar item

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I just upgraded to Exchange 2013.  I can connect and send an email on behalf of another Exchange user.  But I'm having trouble inserting a calendar event on behalf of another user. I'm using Coldfusion 9 and the EWS API.

I get the error;
The system has attempted to use an undefined value, which usually indicates a programming error, either in your code or some system code.

It's pointing to the line;
      appt.Start = '#CreateDateTime(2014, 05,05,09,00,00)#'

Can I hard code a date/time just for testing purposes?

I've tried; appt.Start = '2014/05/05 09:00:00'
but I get the same error.

```
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService" name="service">
<cfset service.init()>
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion" name="version">
<cfset service.init(version.Exchange2010)>

<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials" name="credentials">
<cfset credentials.init("v@t.com","password")>
<cfset service.setCredentials(credentials) />
<cfobject type="Java" class="java.net.URI" name="uri">
<cfset uri.init("https://exch999.serverdata.net/EWS/Exchange.asmx?wsdl")>
<cfset service.setUrl(uri) />
```

The following code was edited as a solution

```
   <cfoutput>
                <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Appointment" name="appointment">
                <cfset appointment.init( service )>
                <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MessageBody" name="MessageBody">
                <!--- <cfset MessageBody.init( service )> --->
                <cfscript>
                    appointment.setStart(#createDateTime(Year(Arguments.EventStartDateTime), Month(Arguments.EventStartDateTime),Day(Arguments.EventStartDateTime), evaluate(Hour(Arguments.EventStartDateTime) - val(attributes.AdminTimeZone)), Minute(Arguments.EventStartDateTime), 0)#);
                    appointment.setEnd(#createDateTime(Year(Arguments.EventEndDateTime), Month(Arguments.EventEndDateTime),Day(Arguments.EventEndDateTime), evaluate(Hour(Arguments.EventEndDateTime) - val(attributes.AdminTimeZone)), Minute(Arguments.EventEndDateTime), 0)#);
                    /*appointment.StartTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local);
                    appointment.EndTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local);*/
                    appointment.setSubject("#Arguments.EventName#");
                    appointment.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("#Arguments.EventDescription#"));
                    /*appointment.IsReminderSet(false);*/
                    appointment.Save();
                    </cfscript>
            </cfoutput>
```

Comment: Is the error due to the extra space in "2014, 05"? If you change it to <cfset appt.Start = '#CreateDateTime(2014,05,05,09,00,00)#'> does that fix it?

Comment: Actually the error was on <cfset service.init(appt)> which should have been <cfset appt.init(service)>.  Now I get the error; You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.

Comment: That error is thrown when you're trying to read something before setting it/getting it. What line is that error thrown on?